# inherited class can not use the variable defined in the base class in node.js ES6 styled class ?

Tags: node.js, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I am using ES6 syntax style to make the inheritance class in node.js, there is two classes, in which the base class is to build a mqtt client, and the inherited class is to extend the base class.

However, the problem is the inherited class can not use the variable defined in the base class.

For example, in my base class, there is a public variable called :  this.mqtt_client, when I tried to use this variable in the inherited class, it always gives a undefined issue

My base class is as followed

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt'),
    EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

class MQTTBaseClass extends EventEmitter{

    constructor( option) {
        super();
        this.mqtt_client = null;
        this.uri = option.uri;
        this.mqttOptions.clientId = option.clientId;
    }

    init(uri, mqttOptions){
        this.mqtt_client = mqtt.connect( uri , mqttOptions ); 
        this.mqtt_client.on('connect', onConnectionSuccess);
        this.mqtt_client.on('error',onConnectionError);
        this.mqtt_client.on('message',onMessageReceived);
        ............
     }
}




class MQTTClass2 extends MQTTBaseClass{

    constructor(option) {
        super(option);
        var self  = this;
        var interval = setInterval(
            function() {
                    self.mqttClient.publish('dddd' , 'ddd' , { retain: false  },function(err){

                    })

        }, 5000);
  }
   ..............
}
```

Comment: Voting to close because questions that are caused by a simple typo are considered off-topic probably because there's little value in retaining them for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made the assumption that the base class init function is being called that defines `this.mqtt_client`.

The issue appears to be a misspelling, you are using `self.mqttClient` where you should be using `self.mqtt_client`.

As a side note you should attempt to use a common variable naming scheme to avoid issues like this in the future: most Javascript code is written using camel case, but there is no rule against using underscores. The important thing is to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

The error is completely correct; `mqttClient` is undefined.

The unrelated `mqtt_client` field from the base class doesn't change anything.